# How do I make a program that removes the same set of values from the 2d arrays?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am new to programming, so if anyone who could explain how to do this in a bit detail. That would be very helpful.
Here's what I could come up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int remove_duplicates(int array[][2]);

int main(){

    int i,j,num;

    printf("Enter the number of sets: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    int sets[num][2];

    printf("Enter elements in the array: ");

    for(i=0;i<num;i++){

        for(j=0;j<2;j++){

            scanf("%d", &sets[i][j]);

        }
    }

    remove_duplicates(sets);

    for(i=0;i<num;i++){

        for(j=0;j<2;j++){

            printf("%d," ,sets[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
}

int remove_duplicates(int array[][2]){

    int i,j,k,n;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){

        for(j=0;j<2;j++){

            if(array[i][j] == array[i+1][j+1]){

                for(k=j;k<n;k++){

                    array[i][k] == array[i][k+1];
                }
                n--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Physically you can not remove elements from an array. You need to track the number of elements in the result array or you should fill the "removed" elements with some value.

Comment: What do you expect if you "remove" a value from an array? You find 0 afterwards at the same place? The array is shorter afterwards? Any other value should be found instead of the removed one? I ask because there are some likely misconception about arrays you might have and which need to be clarified.

Comment: Let's say I have an array[3][2] which contains the element (3,1),(4,5), (3,1) then the function should only print (3,1),(4,5) and ignore the repeating set of elements. In this case, (3,1).

Answer (score 0):

Physically you can not remove elements from an array. You can track the number of actual non-duplicate elements of an array moving them to the beginning of the array.

You can fill the "removed" elements for example with some value if it is required.

Here id a demonstrative program that shows how it can be done. The function that removes duplicate elements declares its parameter as a variable length array. So you will be able to pass to the function two-dimensional arrays of different sizes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

size_t remove_duplicates( size_t m, size_t n, int a[m][n] )
{
    size_t total = m * n;
    size_t k = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < total; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 0;

        while ( j != k && a[j / n][j % n ] != a[i / n ][i % n] ) ++j;

        if ( j == k )
        {
            if ( k != i )
            {
                a[k / n][k % n] = a[i / n][i % n];
            }
            ++k;
        }
    }

    return k;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { M = 3, N = 10 };
    int a[M][N];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            a[i][j] = rand() % ( M * N );
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%2d ", a[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    size_t k = remove_duplicates( M, N, a );

    printf( "There are %zu unique elements in the array\n\n", k );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < k; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%2d ", a[i / N ][i % N] );
        if ( ( i + 1 ) % N == 0 ) putchar( '\n' );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = k; i < M * N; i++ )
    {
        a[i / N][i % N] = 0;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%2d ", a[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look as

```
27 16 22  2 14 24 24 17 12  4 
22 18 10 23  0 15  1 29 20 16 
26 16 19  9 14 23 18 17 18  1 

There are 20 unique elements in the array

27 16 22  2 14 24 17 12  4 18 
10 23  0 15  1 29 20 26 19  9 

27 16 22  2 14 24 17 12  4 18 
10 23  0 15  1 29 20 26 19  9 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```